# Not being able to import modules using Python

Tags: python

I've tried importing modules and I've only had bad luck until now. None of my imports work as Python doesn't seem to be able to find them. If I do paste the import directory on the same folder as my script it'll run but otherwise it won't.

I ran:

```
sys.path
```

And got this awkward result:

```
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

And I highly believe my Python installation wasn't that well performed. What's the best turnaround on this ?

Just seems so confusing. Thank you!

Comment: Can we see what you're trying to import as well? A module in the standard library or something else?

Comment: Why do you think that sys.path is awkward? It looks normal to me.

Comment: Any kind of import. I've tried pillow, I've tried django, python doesn't seem to get hold of any of them.

Comment: @CAB I don't know, it looked awkward to me. Especially because every script I run it isn't able to import any of my modules despite they are all installed on the same folder.

Comment: @TheOlDirtyBastard: How did you install them?

Comment: Using pip. I've already managed to run scripts before with all of my modules on the the lib folder. But now it's not able to import any of them.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are trying to import a non-standard library. If that is what you want to do, you have to first run

```
pip install foo
```

in your system's appropriate console. On windows that would be either cmd or powershell.

Comment: I've already installed all of my modules. It's just not able to import them.

Comment: Can you post the error message you get when you try to import something. Please use a standard library for simplicity.

Comment: I've tried with PIL (Pillow) and I get the error message 'ImportError: No module named PIL'

Comment: Is pillow the only module that you have been trouble loading, because a cursory look over other SO threads makes it seem like pillow is an exception to the standard practices when it come to importing. For simplicity can you try to reproduce the problem on a standard library to isolate whether or not the issue is with installation or with imports.

Comment: Just tried with - https://github.com/nficano/pytube and got the same error. No import works whatsoever unless I paste the library folder on the same folder as the script I'm running.

Answer (score -1):

This question is poorly constructed and there is not enough information provided. But....if you are importing a module for use in your code, you should be writing something like...

```
 import 'module'
 module.usemodule(whatever)
```

Comment: I understand. I'm way beyond that though lol. As I've said on my topic I'm able to run scripts if the import directory is on the same folder as my script.